# How to resolve graphql n+1 issue with graphql-jpa java?

Tags: graphql-java

I am facing the graphql `n+1` issue in one of my applications where I am using graphql with restful webservice in java. I am using `schemagen-graphql` with `spring-data-jpa` for connecting to my oracle db.
I saw so many posts but most of the answer were `graphql-node.js` implementation. Anything related to java will be good.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know much about `schemagen-graphql` and whether it matters here at all but, in general, there's currently 3 options with `graphql-java`:

1. Prefetch what you need when resolving the parent field (i.e. in the parent field's `DataFetcher`). You can look ahead to see exactly which sub-fields are requested by examining the `DataFetchingFieldSelectionSet`.
   If the prefetched data doesn't naturally fit into the result object, you can store it in the `LocalContext` and make use of it in when resolving the child field value. This approach is nicely explained in [this blog post](https://www.graphql-java.com/blog/deep-dive-data-fetcher-results/).
2. Use either the **deprecated** (if you use the classes under `graphql.execution`) or the **experimental** (if use the classes under `graphql.execution.nextgen`) approach of annotating your data fetcher with `@Batched` and using `BatchedExecutionStrategy`.
   This option is simple to understand and use, but ties you to `BatchedExecutionStrategy` (the legacy version doesn't fully respect the specification when it comes to handling nulls).
   It is sadly poorly documented, but it boils down to this:

   1. Annotate the `DataFetcher#get` method with [`@Batched`](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/execution/batched/Batched.java)
   2. In that data fetcher, `DataFetchingEnvironment#getSource` will always return a list of source objects (instead of one).
   3. Such a data fetcher must always return a list of results (of the same length as the list of sources). This allows for a simple way to batch-load objects. An obvious example is loading many rows from a relational DB at once:

> ```
> List<Article> articles = DataFetchingEnvironment.getSource(); //source is a list
> List<Long> authorIds = articles.stream.map(article -> article.getAuthodId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
>
> //fetch all the authors in one go    
> SELECT * FROM Author WHERE author_id IN (authorIds)
> ```

3. Use [`DataLoader`](https://github.com/graphql-java/java-dataloader) to fetch your data instead of fetching it directly. The idea is very similar to the original data-loader JavaScript library. Works only with the default `AsyncExecutionStrategy` and **only for queries** (so don't expect it to work for mutations and subscriptions).

You can provide an instance of `DataLoaderRegistry` in `ExecutionInput`, and you normally want to re-create the data loaders and the registry on each request (batch loaders can be shared if they're stateless):

```
DataLoaderRegistry loaders = ...; //initialize your loaders, usually per request

graphQL.execute(ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
         .query(operation)
         .dataLoaderRegistry(loaders) //add the registry to input
         .build());
```

Then in your `DataFetcher` you can always get to the `DataLoader`
 you need via `DataFetchingEnvironment#getDataLoader(String dataLoaderName)`:

```
return env.getDataLoader("authors").load(article.getAuthorId());
```

As a sidenote, you may want to check out my own library for generating the GraphQL API from Java, [GraphQL-SPQR](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr). Here's [a minimal demonstration](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/blob/master/src/test/java/io/leangen/graphql/BatchingTest.java) of using `@Batched` with it.

As for the DataLoader, the logic is the same as above, and you get to the `DataLoaderRegistry` via `@GraphQLEnvironment` annotation:

```
@GrapgQLQuery
public CompletableFuture<Author> author(@GraphQLContext Article article, @GraphQLEnvironment ResolutionEnvironment env) {
    return env.dataFetchingEnvironment.getDataLoader("authors").load(article.getAuthorId())
}
```

I'll likely also add a specialized annotation like `@DataLoader("authors")` for injecting the loaders directly.